# How are the mappers decided while running a Hive Map Join?

Tags: join, hive, mapreduce, hiveql, hadoop2

This is stated on the wiki page of **Apache Hive**:

> If all but one of the tables being joined are small, the join can be performed as a map only job.The query

`SELECT /*+ MAPJOIN(b) */ a.key, a.value`

`FROM a JOIN b ON a.key = b.key`

> does not need a reducer. For every mapper of A, B is read completely.

How are the number of mappers decided if one of the tables being joined is small but the other is large enough to go out of a single mapper's resources?
Will the join automatically turn into a non-map join then?

Answer (score 0):

The other table cannot be too large.
It is being streamed through the mapper(s).

Comment: That makes me ask another question " Are you suggesting that the other table is taken over by a number of mappers?"

Comment: The small tables are being replicated to all the mappers. The big table is being streamed through the mappers (each row will be streamed only through a single mapper).

Comment: Can you explain the streaming of large tables with example?
Say,a table having 1000 records (small table) when joined with large table(1 million records).

Comment: Are you familiar with local join algorithms, hash join to be specific?

Comment: Sorry for a late reply, I am held up with a few things. Will clarify my other doubts in some time.